# How to resolve total variation $F(u)=f(u)+\lambda\sum_i^N\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u_i(x)|dx$

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, partial-derivative

Given $u(x)=[u_1(x)..u_N(x)]$, $0 \le u_i(x) \le 1, \sum_i^N u_i(x)=1$ and the cost function is:
$$F(u)=f(u(x))+\lambda\sum_i^N\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u_i(x)|dx$$

where $u_i(x)$ is a value that indicate the degree of $x$ and $f(u(x))$ is just simple function and convex function. I want to find optimal $arg \min_u F(u)$ subject to $0 \le u_i(x) \le 1, \sum_i u_i(x)=1$. As I saw that second term is a total variation (TV) of $u$. Could you have me to find $u$? This is what I done

The optimal solution of u is
$$\frac {\partial F(u)}{\partial u}=f'(u)+\lambda\int_{\Omega}...=0$$
$=>u=?$

Comment: There is no analytical solution, however there are many algorithms that can help you solve it in a moderate amount of time. Do you know something about your $f(u)$? Is it continuously differentiable? Is it strongly-convex? Something more?

Also, what is $u_i$? Is it a number? Is it a vector? Please define your problem more precisely, and I or other people will be able to help you.

Comment: $u$ is both a variable and a function of $x$? Something here is not well-posed.

Comment: Thank for see my question. I edited it.

Comment: It's still not well posed. The integral integrates over $x$, so it's a scalar. But $f(u(x))$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: My goal is not resloving $f(u(x))$. I only consider second term.

Comment: I can't see how you can avoid addressing $f(u(x))$, since you're asking for the argmin of the entire function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be unclear about the $f$ part of the energy / cost-function, I'll ignore it ($f \equiv 0$) in what follows. Also, since I imagine you're going to implement this on an actual computer, let's forget the integral, etc., and consider the discretization.

The TV semi-norm can then be written as

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
TV(x) &:= \|\nabla x\|_p = \begin{cases}\|\nabla x\|_1 := \sum_{j=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^d|(\nabla_k x)_j|, &\mbox{ in the anisotropic case,}\\
\|\nabla x\|_{2,1} := \sum_{j=1}^p\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d|(\nabla_k x)_j|^2}, &\mbox{ in the isotropic case}\end{cases}\\
&= \mathrm{max}\{\langle \nabla x, u\rangle | u \in \mathbb{R}^{dp}, \|u\|_{p^*} \le 1\},
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
where each linear operator $\nabla_k \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is the discrete finite-difference gradient operator along the $k$th axis and $\nabla \in \mathbb{R}^{dp \times p}$ is formed by stacking them vertically. Imagine a $d$-dimensional photo with $p$ "pixels". Also note that in the last part of the formula, one has the dual norms $\|.\|_{1^*} = \|.\|_{\infty}$ and $\|.\|_{(2,1)^*} = \|.\|_{2,\infty}$.

It should be clear that the TV semi-norm is non-smooth. Thus your problem is a non-smooth convex optimization problem. Thanks to the formula above, we recognize your problem should be amenable to iterative methods using a scheme like [Nesterov's smoothing](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.295.7816&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (or see [NESTA](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/nesta/), for a "clearer" version of the algorithm for TV in particular).

Relevant literature also includes: [TV in brain imaging](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1101) (optimization of), [benchmarking solvers for TV minimization and co.](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00991743/document), etc.

Hope this helps.